# Dimensionality reduction of a large covariance matrix

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

I have a large covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and I am reducing its dimensionality by using a truncated eigendecomposition. $\Sigma \approx VDV^T$. I remember somewhere that you could also decompose it as $VDV^T + \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries and dimensionality similar to $\Sigma$. Does anybody know this technique?

Can I just assume that diag($\Sigma - VDV^T$) always has positive entries?

Comment: "Can I just assume that diag(Σ−VDV^T) always has positive entries?"---The diagonal entries of a positive semidefinite matrix are nonnegative.

Comment: Of course!. That has to be the argument!. Thanks @Michael